# What's with all the users named InteractiveMesh?

Tags: discussion, users

I have been doing some research today using SEDE and I have noticed [40 accounts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1234849/interactivemesh) which are all called "InteractiveMesh".

Some of them have a single answer and some of these answers are signed "From: August". The website doesn't look very serious, which makes me suspicious that it could be some elaborate spam.

Is it something to be concerned about?

Comment: It could be a user who just didn't understand the site well and kept creating new accounts.  All the answers I look at are are about java-3d; which is also what the interactivemesh site appears to be about too.

Comment: As long as the accounts are not interacting with each other, there is nothing inherently wrong with this, right?

Comment: @yivi if my theory that it was just someone confused about how the site works is right there's nothing wrong with it; if Dharman is right and it's an attempt to use legit answers to sneak spam/seo under the radar the accounts probably should be nuked leaving the answers belonging to deleted user123456, etc.  The answers themselves appear to be legitimate if mostly - meh grade - responses to the questions; so I'm not in favor of destroying them if the accounts go.

Comment: I know of multiple users on SciFi.SE who intentionally create new accounts for every answer they post. I know not why, but I'm sure they have their reasons.

Comment: @F1Krazy you can always request merge to your master account if question gain positive votes, it is much harder to "unmerge" question if it got a negative attention. I don't understand why company does not make it supported - it guarantees a lot of "new users" on all sites... (It does not look like quality will suffer anymore :) )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That would be an abuse of restrictions. We already ban and delete account that do that.

Comment: @Dharman sure... but I don't think "it is abuse of restrictions" ever stopped anyone who is trying to bypass restrictions... And to ban we have to  find them :)

Comment: You are researching users on SEDE?

Comment: Most recent activity on any of the accounts was more than 5 years ago.